# VB.Net: How to populate the combobox from Database with float values

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I have 2 columns in my database and 2 ComboBoxes in my form which are connected to each other. One contains float values and the other contains VarChar. I use the code below and it works fine for the one with VarChar, but not the one with float. What is wrong?

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Code = 2"
DBCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlstr, DBConn)
DBDr = DBCmd.ExecuteReader

While (DBDr.Read())
CBox_TBand.SelectedItem = DBDr("TB")
CBox_State.SelectedItem = DBDr("State")
End While
DBCmd.Dispose()
DBDr.Close()
```

TB column contains float and State column contains Varchar.

Comment: Please show the code that assigns the combo-boxes with DataSource, ValueMember and DisplayMember.

Comment: I think it should have something to do with the datatype.
I even tried writing CBox_TBand.SelectedItem=(DBDr("TB")).toString, but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried changing TB's datatype to VarChar in the database, and now it is working; but how can I fix it if I want TB to remain float?

Comment: Does the combo show the "float" values? You may try adding .ToString() to DBDr("TB").

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you are losing formatting when converting from DB's Float to String. Try this:

```
CBox_TBand.SelectedItem = Decimal.Parse(DBDr("TB")).ToString()
```